# Preview generated PDF on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, winnovative, document-preview

I'm generating a PDF document in code-behind using [Winnovative's HTML to PDF](http://www.winnovative-software.com/html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx) converter, and I would like to preview the document in a container on the page.

This is for an intranet application and all of the end users have the latest version of Reader installed, so compatibility is not an issue. The preview should be fully featured too, with the ability to zoom in and out, print, save, email, etc.

I've seen quite a few examples searching online, but I would appreciate some suggestions based on actual experience. Ideally, it would be great to find a server control with configurable options that can create the element(s) and register the necessary client scripts.

Comment: +1 for asking for actual experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need the `<embed>` Tag. Put something like this in you page and you can show the users the PDF in the webpage itself.

```
<h3>Sample Pdf</h3>
<embed width="80%" height="80%" name="plugin" src="http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

You will get all the features of Adobe Reader. Since its an Intranet app you should be able to Make sure Required Plugins  are already installed on Client Machines.